# Asp.Net Mvc 5 Azure Active Directory Get and save user profile image on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to get profile image of logged in user then save it on the server.

This code is from Startup.Auth.cs

```
 AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                           {
                               var code = context.Code;
                               ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                               string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                               string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                               AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));  
                               AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                               code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                               AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
                               Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
                               Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);
                               ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(result.AccessToken));
                               var res = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
                               .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
                               .ExecuteAsync();
                               IUser user = res.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

                               var image = await user.ThumbnailPhoto.DownloadAsync();


                           }
```

await user.ThumbnailPhoto.DownloadAsync() throws this error

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_ResourceNotFound","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource 'thumbnailPhoto' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, the main possible reason for the issue is that the thumbnail photo hadn’t be set for the user. I can reproduce this issue when I run the code before I set thumbnail for the user. Then the code works well for me.

You can check whether the thumbnail for set by login the new azure protal and compare the image from top right corner like figure below:
[image]

I set it through PowerShell from local Active Directory and sync it to Azure AD by Azure AD connect:

```
Set-ADUser user1 -Replace @{thumbnailPhoto=([byte[]](Get-Content "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\me.jpg" -Encoding byte))}
```